# I have to develop the document status page where stages includes steps of home agreement

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I have used stepper widget but it needs to jump at any step and save the state throughout the app even if we navigate to another page? How to do it?

Comment: Your question needs a little more clarity regarding saving the state of what? State of data? State of the entire Stepper widget?

I have assumed State of Data and answered the question accordingly.

Comment: @PreetShah State of the entire stepper widget

Comment: I suggest using provider will help with managing the state of the application.

Answer (score -1):

Stepper allows you to move to any step without any issues. The `onStepTapped` function is for the same purpose of navigation.

You can use the `onStepContinue` function to validate and save intermediate data and entire data.

I hope this helps.

```dart
int n = 2; // number of steps
    return Stepper(
      controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails details) {
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
              child: const Text('Save'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: details.onStepCancel,
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      currentStep: _index,
      onStepCancel: () {
        if (_index > 0) {
          setState(() {
            _index -= 1;
          });
        }
      },
      onStepContinue: () {
        // You can have a save command over here
        // that validates the fields and then saves the data after validation
        if (_index < n - 1) {
          print("Validating step ${_index + 1} data.");
          print("Saving step ${_index + 1} data.");
          setState(() {
            _index += 1;
          });
        }
        else if(_index == n-1){
          // perform a validation over here and
          // navigate to the next page
          print("Validating entire data.");
          print("Saving entire data.");
        }
      },
      onStepTapped: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _index = index;
        });
      },
      steps: <Step>[
        Step(
          title: const Text('Step 1 title'),
          content: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: const Text('Content for Step 1')),
        ),
        const Step(
          title: Text('Step 2 title'),
          content: Text('Content for Step 2'),
        ),
      ],
    );
```